# how to load javaScript code to textarea in ExtjS

Tags: javascript, extjs

how to load javaScript code to textarea in ExtjS Form panel??
this my code but still error

my Code:

```
 {
     fieldLabel: 'Code'
     xtype: 'textareafield',
     autoScroll: 'auto',
     width: '100%',
     height: '100%',
     loader: {
         url: 'https://localhost/springapp/js/app/view/component/codesnippet.js',
         autoLoad: true,
         renderer: function(loader, response, active) {
                 var text = new String(response.responseText);
                 text = text.replace(/&/mg, '&');
                 text = text.replace( //mg, '>');
                 text = text.replace(/\"/mg, '"');
                 text = text.replace(/\t/g, ' '); 
                 text = text.replace(/\r?\n/g, ''); 
                 text = text.replace( //g,'');
                 text = text.replace( //g, ' ');
                 loader.getTarget().update(text);
                 return true;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the error message from the Console.

Comment: First of all the code has some syntax errors. The following line is wrong `text = text.replace( //mg, '>');`. It evaluates to `text = text.replace(` as you have commented the rest of the line. The same applies for other lines too. However, the code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check your js file codesnippet.js by path /springapp/js/app/view/component/, seems that no, and don't forget cross-domain restriction([loader](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.TextArea-cfg-loader) can load remote content)

Regex error's

```
1. text = text.replace( //g, '>'); // what is symbol for replace?
2. text = text.replace(//g, '');// what is symbol for replace?
3. text = text.replace(//g, ' ');// what is symbol for replace?
```

[Look fiddle(delay a few second for load script)](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/gvt)